# Compiler Error - 'class Item' has no member named 'a' Line 46

Tags: c++, class, encapsulation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Item{
    private:
        string type;
        string abbrv;
        string uID;
        int aircraft;
        double weight;
        string destination;
    public:
        Item(string t, string a, string u, int aC, double w, string d){
            type = t;
            abbrv = a;
            uID = u;
            aircraft = aC;
            weight = w;
            destination = d;
        }
    Item(){}
    Item(Item & i){
        type = i.type;
        abbrv = i.abbrv;
        uID = i.uID;
        aircraft = i.aircraft;
        weight = i.weight;
        destination = i.destination;
   }
    void print(){
        cout << "ULD: " << type << endl;
        cout << "Abbreviation: " << abbrv << endl;
        cout << "ULD-ID: " << uID << endl;
        cout << "Aircraft: " << aircraft << endl;
        cout << "Weight: " << weight << " Kilograms" << endl;
        cout << "Destination: " << destination << endl;
   }

    friend void kilotopound(Item);
};
void kilotopound(Item I){
    cout<<"Weight in Pounds: " << I.weight * 2.2 << " LBS " << endl;
}
bool operator == (Item &ab, Item &bc){
    if((ab.a == bc.a) && (ab.u == bc.u)){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
int main(){
    Item I ("Pallet", "PAG32597IB", "PAG", 737, 3321, "SEA");
    I.print();
    kilotopound(I);
    cout << "\nCopy\n\n";
    Item I2(I);
    I.print();
    kilotopound(I);
    cout<<"\nSecond Object\n\n";
    I2.print();
    kilotopound(I2);
    Item unit1 ("Pallet", "PAG32597IB", "PAG", 737, 3321, "SEA");
    Item unit2(unit1),unit3(I);
    if (unit1 == unit2)
    cout << "\nUnit1 and Unit2 are the same \n";
    else
    cout << " \nUnit1 and Unit2 aren't the same \n";
    if (unit2 == unit3)
    cout << " \nUnit2 and Unit3 are the same\n";
    else
    cout << " \nUnit2 and Unit3 aren't the same\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Hi! So the code above gives me the error 'class Item' has no member named 'a' at line 46, which is where to bool operator is. Can someone help me out with basically just trying to get the code to function and explain why I get the error even though I have the data made public?
I'm pretty lost at why this happens even if the abbreviations are already stated. Also I tried just using abbrv and uID but got an error that the data was private.
Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't .a be .aircraft. You item doesn't have a member 'a' but it has a member 'aircraft'

Answer (score 1):

`a` is the parameter of `Item`'s constructor `Item(string t, string a, string u, int aC, double w, string d)`, not an "alias" of `Item::abbrv`. Constructors are functions, and the parameters of a function are only available inside the function body.

There is no "member alias" in C++, nor is there any concept of "properties" (like in C#). To provide read-only access to `Item::abbrv`, define a "getter" function for it:

```cpp
// Public member function of class Item:
const string& getAbbrv() const {
    return abbrv;
}
```

Comment: so would I need to define getters and setters for ULD to Destination?

Comment: @JimCrawford for each of the data members you wish to provide access to, define a getter and/or a setter.